# What is the minumum info you need to tell if an object is a circle?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-vision, object-detection

So basically I have a program that runs through an image of objects and is supposed to count the number of cirlces. I can more or less accurately detect all objects and store the following results of each object:
Area(number of pixels), xPosition, YPosition and like the bounds.

I tried differentiating circles from non-circles by assuming every object was a circle, finding the radius and using pi*r^2 to get the area. If that area matched the number of pixels then it was a circle.

However this leads to a few errors. Such as when an object takes up the same area as a circle would but is not a circle.

Any idea's as to what I can try? It also fails in the noisy cases since my algorithm doesnt save pixels that are dark (Which is counted as like the background)

Edit: I cant use any already established algorithm such as the Hugh Transform

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is a [circle Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform), which is supported by (I would imagine) most computer vision libraries, like [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), for example.

Comment: Use the bounds: simultaneously go to center and middle from left and right and from top and bottom, and see if the pixel count is similar/same location.
`top=0; bottom=10; left=0; right=10;`
`isCircle=true;
while (top<bottom AND left<right) {
  if(rowPixelCount(top)~rowPixelCount(bottom) AND columnPixelCount(left)~columnPixelCount(right)) {
  top++, bottom--, left++, right++;
  };
else isCircle=false;
};`

Comment: "Such as when an object takes up the same area as a circle would but is not a circle." Can you please show an example of such an object? Depending of your definition of "radius", this situation might be impossible. Also, I assume you meant "the area of the enclosed disc" because a circle doesn't have an area.

Comment: @iAmOren Hey, thanks that makes sense. Only problem is, I don't store each pixel of the disc. I only store the min X value, max X value, min Y, max Y... and thats enough to calculate radius etc.

Any opinions on how I should efficently store the pixels of the disc as I loop through them so that I can use your method? I don't want to have to use too much memory

Comment: If you have the bounds, you can deduce center and area.
How about sampling the corners and the center (the corners colors should be similar and considerably different than the center).
That could give you a "diamond", so sample NE/NW/SE/SW at a distance from the center of more than half a diagonal but less than radius: if all four similar to center - could be circle.
So: center(x,y), radius(1/2 width == 1/2 height), and colors for: top-left, top-right, botton-left, bottom-right, NE, NW, SE, and SW. - as soon as you collect the data, you can use the check above and decide to keep/drop.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, only the circles have a perimeter equal to the square root of 2π times the (filled) area. But you need an accurate assessment of the perimeter.

Alternatively, find the circle parameters (coordinates of the center and radius) by any method*, and check that the pixels of the contour fulfill the circle equation (compute the average deviations).

*If the shape is not a circle, those parameters will have "random" values, but this does not matter.